# Why is this sum an expectation over iid Bernoulli random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For each $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$, let $\alpha_{ij}$ be a nonnegative real parameter. Moreover, let $t_{i} \in \{-1,+1\}$ for every $i = 1,...,n$. I have the following sum:
$$\sum_{t_{1},...,t_{n} \in \{-1,1\}}\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n}(1+\alpha_{ij}t_{i}t_{j}).$$

My professor said this sum is an average over Bernoulli iid random variables:
$$\sum_{t_{1},...,t_{n} \in \{-1,1\}}\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n}(1+\alpha_{ij}t_{i}t_{j}) = \mathbb{E}[\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n}(1+\alpha_{ij}t_{i}t_{j})]$$
where the expectation is over a set of $n$ iid Bernoulli variables. Why is that? I have no clue.

Comment: The right hand side of your equation should probably look like $\mathbb{E}[\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (1+\alpha_{ij}X_iX_j)]$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli variables taking the values $-1$ and $1$ with the same probability. Then use properties of expectation and the fact that the rv are iid to conclude.